# Google Charts - How to add percentage sign as units on vAxis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization

How do I get google charts to display percentage sign after each visible y value on the vAxis?   Right now my graph only shows integer values on the y axis.

I researched the issue and found formatter which only renders percentage sign (%) within the tool tip that occurs when I hover on a particular bar (on a bar graph).

How can I get the chart to show % on each y axis values on my bar graph?

**JS**

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).resize(function(){
          drawStuff();
        });
      });
      function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Product', 'Profitability'],
          ["Product 1", 12],
          ["Product 2", 11],
          ["Product 3", 10],
          ["Product 4", 9],
          ["Product 5", 8],
          ["Product 6", 7],
          ["Product 7", 6],
          ["Product 8", 5],
          ["Product 9", 4],
          ["Product 10", 3]
        ]);


        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
              {suffix: '%'});
        formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

        var options = {
          title: 'LEADERS',
          width: '100%',
          colors: ["#949494"],
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chart: { title: 'LEADERS',
                   //subtitle: 'popularity by percentage'
                 },
          bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
            x: {
              0: { side: 'bottom'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          },
          bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
          vAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, format: '#\'%\''}
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      };
```

**Edit...**

The following edit achieves the desired creation of % units after the y axis tick marks but I can not get it to work otherwise.

```
setTimeout(function(){
          $("text").each(function(){
            if ($.isNumeric($(this).text()))
            {
              $(this).text($(this).text() + "%");
            }
          });
        }, 250);
```

Comment: try: `format: "#%"` No `\` needed.

Comment: No change using the specified format

Comment: Using a hack I tried `$("text[x='14.5']").each(function(){$(this).text($(this).text() + "%")});` and got percentage signs. But I am still looking for a more appropriate solution.

Comment: You are using the Materials version which is in beta still, they lack some options normal charts use. Specifically what options aren't available wasn't documented. I assume Google wasn't specific because betas are a work in progress. If you try asking the same question next month, you might get a better solution.

Comment: If you like the look of Materials, you could use a normal chart then add this : `theme: 'materials'`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I am satisfied with the produced code, but if there are any issues I will try the normal chart.

Comment: fyi: the option is singular -- `theme: 'material'` -- also --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)